# At what point(s) during the narrative do the voices change?

Tags: spec-ops-the-line

A 'bark' is a line of dialogue spoken by a character in order to provide tactical information.  Examples of barks include "Reloading!" or "Flashlights off, I hear a witch!"

When creating Spec Ops: The Line, one of the design decisions that the dev team made was to have several separate sets of 'barks'.

> At the beginning of the game, these are entirely professional, such as Walker's command to *"Eliminate that sniper.*" or "*Need assistance.*" from your squadmates.
>
>  As the game continues and the team is faced with the horrors of war, the dialogue also changes.  By the end of the game, Captain Walker is screaming "*I want that sniper dead!*" and you're likely to hear "*Help me, you son of a bitch!*" from your squad.

**At what point or points during the narrative do these changes happen?**

Comment: Wow, I never even noticed that until I read this.  What a good single player story.

Comment: @turbo this subtle change was one of my favorite aspects of spec-ops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "barks" change gradually; they don't go from military professional to angry disillusioned immediately. The "barks" become more aggressive as you work through the story, say as you descend into the heat of darkness. Generally, the "barks" and character's reactions change after a major plot development, which is generally represented by a longer cut scene.